# Mark garbled code

Tags: geoserver

GeoServer publishes the vector point layer but the displayed label is garbled. The text content in SHP layer is Myanmar language. I don't know what font needs to be set to display normally。

The CSS code I set is as follows:

```
[@scale <10000000] { 
   label: [name];
   label-follow-line: true; 
   label-max-angle-delta:15; 
   font-style:"normal";
   font-fill: #000000;
   font-size: 18;
   font-weight: normal;
   label-anchor: 0.5 0;
   label-offset: 0 10; 
   label-max-displacement: 200;
   label-auto-wrap: 200; 
   mark: symbol(circle), symbol(circle);
    :mark{
      size: 8px, 14px;
      fill:#FF0000, null;
      stroke:#FF0000, #FF0000;
      stroke-width:1,1.5; 
    }; 
   mark-opacity: 12%;
 }
```

Comment: what is the text of the label? what language is that? does your font support those characters?

Comment: The text is in Burmese Language, and I can't use Burmese fonts

Comment: Then it isn't going to work - with out a font that can display the glyphs then you will get little boxes

Comment: So I don't know how to solve this problem now. I don't know if I have encountered the same problem?

Comment: here are some font suggestions - https://www.myanmarhouse.com.mm/en/tools/myanmar-font-download

Comment: I tried all fonts, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

From a little googling I found [this page which proposes 3 fonts to support Myanmar characters](https://www.myanmarhouse.com.mm/en/tools/myanmar-font-download). I added them to my system and restarted GeoServer so that it would see them. Some simple experiments found that the [Zawgyi font](https://www.myanmarhouse.com.mm/assets/download/Zawgyi-One.ttf) gave the best results for my test data (the [places shapefile](https://mapcruzin.com/free-myanmar-country-city-place-gis-shapefiles.htm)) though since I can't read Burmese I have to assume that those strings are correct.

[image]

Comment: I added this font to my operating system, but it still displays garbled code. It seems that the Myanmar font in your screenshot is not? My Myanmar text is as follows: ၼမ်ႉၸၢင်、ဘားအံ

Comment: As I said I had mixed results with the fonts, you may need to try the other ones

Comment: I tried many fonts, but they didn't work. My data was downloaded from openstreet, places_ Layer of city place names

Comment: May be your data is corrupted or loaded in the wrong encoding - can you provide a link to it? or experiment with the one I was testing with

Comment: http://120.77.87.164:8888/test_web/myanmar_places_city.rar。This is the point layer I use.

Comment: The installed "zawgyi one" font was not found in the available font list of GeoServer, but it was found by the system in terms of the total number, and the keywords such as "zawgyi one" could not be found in the available font list

Comment: then you only installed it for your self and not the user running GeoServer